# deeppavlov 'Chainer' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, nlp

скачал конфиг модели  из репозитория deeppavlolv , казалось бы.

```
model = build_model(model_config, download=True)
```

модель сбилдилась, но почему-то

```
faq = train_model(model)
```

выдает ошибку'Chainer' object has no attribute 'get'. 
хотя в документации прям так и написано чтобы обучать модели. Или я что-то не так понимаю